# REST query input geometry

Tags: query, api, arcgis-rest-api, census

I'm trying to get a list of surrounding counties using https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/ but I am having trouble querying their ArcGIS REST server.

My goal is to send a county (I know the GEOID), get that geometry, and then query with that polygon to get anything that touches it.

I've boiled this down to a point to try to figure out what is going wrong.

I feel like this should give me the county that the point is in but I get a "Failed to execute query" error.

[TigerWeb Census](https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_ACS2022/MapServer/78/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&timeRelation=esriTimeRelationOverlaps&geometry=-80.172041000202555%2C+36.953448999687616&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&havingClause=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnExtentOnly=false&sqlFormat=none&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=html)

The equivalent query seems to work on the ESRI USA counties service, so I'd like to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the Census data.

[ESRI USA Counties](https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Counties/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=-80.172041000202555%2C+36.953448999687616&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&relationParam=&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnCentroid=false&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&defaultSR=&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=html&token=)

Comment: For some reason, possibly a defect, it is choking on the distance value of `0.0`.  Either remove a distance value completely or set it to some very small value.

Comment: Thanks. I would not have thought to check that and that works well.